# Regular Expressions for sequences other than strings

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

Do there exist regular expression engines for sequences other than strings? It occurs to me that there is nothing special about strings that restricts regex to them, they are just sequences of characters.

For example, if I had list of `Buffalo` objects, and I wanted to check if my list matched between 4 and 7 `Buffalo` over 5 ft tall, followed by a white `Buffalo`, followed by a backreference to the 4-7 `Buffalo` before, and then the end of the list, are there engines to support something like this?

I don't currently have a need for this, just curious.

Answer (score 0):

regular expressions work on strings, not objects. If you want to match object keys or values you are going to have to iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Boost's Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) and C++11's [std::basic_regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex). It seems to allow you to specify the type and some traits as template parameters. However, it doesn't give you a way to do more complex comparisons on types or methods.

In general, regular expressions are very tied to the notion of equality of the underlying objects themselves. More than that would be an additional feature set foreign to the concept of "[regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)".

The question this raised for me is... why doesn't there seem to be a library that does what you're proposing? And I think the key here is that regular expressions are commonly used for handling semi-structured or informally structured data. But objects are very formally structured, even in relatively typeless languages such as Javascript. And at that point, programmers tend to use the language constructs to structure data as they see fit rather than re-interpret more generic structuring since that seems to make things less idiomatic. In fact, regexes where they're unnecessary seem to be regarded as hacks.

Trying to imagine use cases where I'd want a full-blown pattern matching language for an ordered sequence of objects, I end up only with scenarios where a log of structured events might have some interesting inter-event happenings. For example, looking for higher level patterns in a packet sniffed network. Maybe there's some other data-mining applications I'm not thinking of?